# Have to use C# dll to call C++ dll?

Tags: c#, .net, c++

Do I have to create a C# DLL to call C++ DLL or I can call it directly from my C# application?

Comment: Please don't duplicate the tags ("C#") in the title. Just leave them in the tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call it directly [with PInvoke and the `DllImport` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx).  Assuming, of course, that it has standard C entry points, not compiler-specific C++ entry points.

Unless you were talking about C++/CLI, in which case you would reference the .NET DLL exactly as you would reference any other .NET DLL.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a Win32 navite dll directly from your code using P/Invoke.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx