# How to include visual C++ generated DLL into c# code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll, dllimport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Have to use C# dll to call C++ dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073303/have-to-use-c-sharp-dll-to-call-c-dll)

This is my first program related to `importing external dll to my C# code`. I created a `DLl` (Win 32 Dynamic Link Library) from `visual C++ code`. Let me paste the content of `.cpp and .h file`:

```
#include...
#
using namespace std;
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule,DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{   
      return TRUE;
}

unsigned char* decrypt(string stringKSN, string key){ #### some code
     convert(key_new);
return key_new
}

void convert(char * a) { ## return "some_value"
}
```

I build the `visual c++` project and it created a `finalDLL.dll`.Now i want to use this `dll` into my `c#` code. I searched it on google and found that we can import the `dll` in `c#` project with the help of `p/invoke exports`. But when i compare the sample code with the above one it was totally different.

I am not able to test whether `finalDLL.dll` is corrected or corrupted?

Please help me to complete my import task.

Comment: can't you simply add a reference to your DLL in C# project?

Comment: It shows me following error:
A reference to the "....dll" could not be added.Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

Comment: what about adding a reference to *project* that built the DLL ?

Comment: @CapelliC didn't got your above comment

Comment: Look at this Thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193243/importing-c-dll-in-c-sharp-project

Comment: when you select 'add reference' you can choice the type of the 'object' to reference. I used (when I had MSVS) a workspace with multiple projects inside, usually some DLL and then the application code that used them

Comment: Oh i forgot to tell you that i have created a Win32 Dynamic-Link Library

Comment: @CapelliC Will it create a effect on importing?

Comment: you are better of to forget about P/Invoke all together, and instead either write your decrupt function completely in C++/CLI or else make a seperate C++/CLI dll that calls your original dll

Comment: possible duplicate of [Have to use C# dll to call C++ dll?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073303/have-to-use-c-sharp-dll-to-call-c-dll) and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574208/how-do-i-use-the-c-dll-in-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995513/using-c-dll-in-c-sharp-project

Comment: @stijn Please check my question. I am not creating the c# dll

Comment: sorry but that doesn't matter, this topic has been asked and answered in all it's forms here, just search for `c++ c# dll` for example. The answers are always the same... either you use P/Invoke and make sure to use correct calling conventions etc (hence no std::string arguments), or you make a CLI layer in between.